# Bind a 2D array to a PDO SQL statement

Tags: php, sqlite

How do I bind an array **WITHOUT** a key (non associative array) to a PDO SQL statement?

Say I want to insert all 3 entries from `$fruits` to the database:

```
$fruits = array(
 array('apple','red','sweet'),
 array('lemon','yellow','bitter'),
 array('bannana','yellow','sweet')
);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `fruits` (`name`, `color`, `taste`) VALUES ( ???? )");

$stmt->bindValue(??);

$stmt->execute();
```

I know it can be done with associative array ([Binding multiple values in pdo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344741/binding-multiple-values-in-pdo)) but in this scenario The array have no key.

Comment: What do you mean by array have no key?

Comment: I meant that you can't refer to it like `$fruits['color']`.

Comment: Then use $fruits[0], $fruits[1]... etc

Comment: How so? Can you post an example as an answer, please?

Comment: By the way your array synatx is wrong, it is 2d array, right?

Comment: right. it is a 2D array. I just fixed it.

Comment: It's the same principle, just change the placeholder. 
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#103287

Comment: @vsmoraes . ok so I'll have to use `foreach`. I though there were another way of doing it. Post as an answer, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put it inside a loop...

```
$fruits = array(
  array('apple','red','sweet'),
  array('lemon','yellow','bitter'),
  array('bannana','yellow','sweet')
);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `fruits` (`name`, `color`, `taste`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

foreach ($fruits as $row) {
  $stmt->bindValue($row);
}

$stmt->execute();
```