# BindParam Foreach Loop not working

Tags: php, loops, pdo, bindparam

This is not working for some reason, same loop works fine with a SELECT statement but not an INSERT statement.

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO users(user_id,password) VALUES(?,?)";
 $data = array();
 $data[1] = "1";
 $data[2] = "password";
 public function insert($sql,$data){
    $newQuery = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    //pass $value as a reference to the array item
    foreach ($data as $key => &$value) {  
    // bind the variable to the statement
        $newQuery->bindParam($key,$value); 
    } 
    $newQuery->execute();
}
```

Comment: what does your php error log tell you ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344741/binding-multiple-values-in-pdo

Comment: imo, just use 'bindValue' with PDO unless you really need bindParam (BLOB)?

Comment: @RyanVincent yeah, on consideration you are correct. I was taking the `?` as MySQL- only placeholders. (Partly as I see most of the whole point of PDO being that it uses *named* placeholders)

Comment: @martin, I agree with you that using named placeholders makes a lot of sense. Especially if the query is changed and, say,  new placeholders can just be  added at the end of the list.

Comment: Thank you guys, I'm going to try that.

Comment: Hi Guys, that didn't work! Any other solution?

Comment: For some reason i'm not getting any error!

Comment: You set PDO to create exceptions on error? see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992795/set-pdo-to-throw-exceptions-by-default.

Comment: imo: lose the `foreach loop` completely as it adds nothing useful. Change the `$newQuery->execute();` to  `$newQuery->execute($data);`. And ensure the $data array has `user_id` as the first element.

Comment: @RyanVincent That worked, Thank You!