# Inserting Array Values using PDO and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I need to insert arrayed values into a database using PDO, I have this code working but it doesn't use arrays (this was prototype code before I got arrayed input)

This is a snippet from the form for input showing the arrays (date isn't arrayed):

```
echo "<tbody><tr><td><input type='text' name='tipster[]'></td>";

echo "<td><input type='text' name='date' value=''>";

echo "<td><input type='text' name='tip[]'></td>"; 

echo "<td><input type='text' name='outcome[]'></td>"; 

echo "<td><input type='text' name='odds[]'></td>";
```

This is some of the code to process the submitted form:

```
$tipster = $_POST['tipster'];
$date= $_POST['date'];
$tip= $_POST['tip'];
$outcome= $_POST['outcome'];
$odds= $_POST['odds'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO bets (tipster,date,tip,outcome,odds) VALUES (:tipster,:date,:tip,:outcome,:odds)";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':tipster', $tipster, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':tip', $tip, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':outcome', $outcome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':odds', $odds, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();
```

How would I change my code to cater for arrayed values being submitted?

I want a new row input for each row on the form, so if the user enters 3 rows of data I want 3 new rows in the database.  The form uses javascript to allow the user to enter as many rows as they like.

Thanks.

Comment: define "arrayed values" you are talking about. try to put more effort into questions you are asking

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding multiple values in pdo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344741/binding-multiple-values-in-pdo)

Comment: Now it's clear. There are a lot of examples on SO already. What is your particular problem?

Comment: You can use `foreach` and write your insert query in that. And set the `size of array` as your `size of  foreach`