# Function for PDO preapred stament not work and get error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I make 2 function with same use to take over PDO Preapred Statement, but both of not work .

Function 1 :

```
function doSave($array, $table) {
if (count($array) == 0) {
    throw new Exception('Array cant be empty');
} else {
    global $connect;
    //prepare the query first
    $prepare_1 = 'INSERT INTO' . ' ' . $table . ' '; //start preparing
    $columns = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $columns[] = ':' . $key; //gets all columns and add commas
    }
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $keye[] =  $key; //gets all columns and add commas
    }
    $keyes = implode(', ', $keye);
    $column = implode(', ', $columns);
    //now you can combine everything and prepare
    $stmt99 = $connect->prepare($prepare_1 .'('.$keyes.')'. ' VALUES (' . $column . ')'); 
    //remember to add the values. also test this section as its not tested

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $test[] = "':" . $key ."' => ". $value;
         }
        $tests = implode(', ', $test);          
        $stmt99->execute($tests);
}
}
```

When i insert the data i got no error and no data get insert to my database

Function 2 :

```
function doSave($array, $table) {
if (count($array) == 0) {
    throw new Exception('Array cant be empty');
} else {
    global $connect;
    //prepare the query first
    $prepare_1 = 'INSERT INTO' . ' ' . $table . ' '; //start preparing
    $columns = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $columns[] = ':' . $key; //gets all columns and add commas
    }
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $keye[] =  $key; //gets all columns and add commas
    }
    $keyes = implode(', ', $keye);
    $column = implode(', ', $columns);
    //now you can combine everything and prepare
    $stmt99 = $connect->prepare($prepare_1 .'('.$keyes.')'. ' VALUES (' . $column . ')'); 
    //remember to add the values. also test this section as its not tested

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $test[] = '$stmt99->bindparam('.'":' . $key .'",'. $value.'); ';
         }
        $tests = implode(' ', $test);
            $tests;
        $stmt99->execute();
}
}
```

i got error when use this function :

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound
```

This How i use the function :

```
$array = array('categoryName' => $categoryName, 'categorySort' => $categorySort);
doSave($array, 'category');
```

This the source of the array :

```
if (!empty($_POST["categoryName"])) {
        $categoryName = ($_POST["categoryName"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$categoryName)) {
          $errMsg = "<div class='alert alert-danger text-center'><strong>Hanya boleh huruf.</strong></div>"; 
        }
    }  
    if ($_POST["categorySort"] == $check['categorySort']) {
         $errMsg = "<div class='alert alert-danger text-center'><strong>Urutan sudah digunakan.</strong></div>"; 
    }else{
        $categorySort = ($_POST["categorySort"]);
        if (!is_numeric($_POST['categorySort'])) {
          $errMsg = "<div class='alert alert-danger text-center'><strong>Hanya boleh angka.</strong></div>"; 
        } 
    }
```

What possibly go wrong from this 2 function both function for same use. Function 1 (named param) Function 2 (bindparam) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is not fully tested but displayed what I expected when I tested it using echo statements.

You should check the return value of `prepare` before attempting to execute the statement because it will return false if the statement failed to be prepared correctly.

```
function doSave( $array, $table ) {
    try{
        /* if you throw exceptions you should catch them!! */

        if( empty( $array ) )throw new Exception('Array cant be empty');
        if( empty( $table ) )throw new Exception('Table name cannot be empty');
        global $connect;

        /* placeholder variables */
        $prepare = $columns = $values = array();
        $result = false;

        $table = preg_replace("@[',\.]@",'',$table);// whatever chars deemed appropriate to replace
        $prepare[]="insert into `{$table}` ";

        /* iterate through source array */
        foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
            $columns[] = $key;
            $values[ $key ] = $value;
        }

        $strcolumns = implode('`,`',$columns);
        $strplaceholders = ':'.implode(', :',$columns);

        /* append columns and placeholders */
        $prepare[]="( `$strcolumns` ) values ( $strplaceholders );";

        /* finalise sql statement */
        $sql=implode('',$prepare);

        $stmt = $connect->prepare( $sql );
        if( $stmt ){
            /* bind the params */
            foreach( $values as $key => $value ) $stmt->bindParam( ':'.$key, $value );

            /* execute the statement */
            $result = $stmt->execute();
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Error preparing sql statement');
        }
        return $result;
    }catch( Exception $e ){
        exit( $e->getMessage() );
    }
}
```

The assumption I made for the code was an input array like this

```
$t='mytable';
$a=array(
    'id'    =>  '303',
    'name'  =>  'bob',
    'size'  =>  'small',
    'weight'=>  'heavy'
);
```

Comment: it succes input to server but the input for categoryName become the input categorySort . i do some change how i use the function

Comment: ? don't understand what you mean

Comment: i do input categoryName = "Tech" categorySort ="3" . but what server get is categoryName ="3" categorySort="3"

Comment: RamRaider, as the table name is supplied by PHP and is not hard coded, I would recommend `preg_replace()`ing invalid characters or as a minimum, encasing this string in backticks. Also check if `$table` is empty.

Comment: Can you show the source array because I made certain assumptions about that with my code

Comment: i include on my question is that what you ask for ? RamRaider

Answer (score 0):

> NOTE:
>   You have two functions both with the same name. How is PHP meant to know the which function you're calling?

**Function 2:**

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $test[] = '$stmt99->bindparam('.'":' . $key .'",'. $value.'); ';
         }
```

Because you encased this in [single] quotes, this value is no longer an object method call but is just a string. This means that when you then `implode` this array all you're making is a longer string.

Also, because you're using single quotes, PHP will not recognise the value `$stmt99` as being a PHP object reference, instead taking it literally as *dollar sign, s character, t character, m character,* etc....

So PDO has no values to bind into the SQL given.

**Fix:**

```
 foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
     $stmt99->bindparam(":" . $key , $value);
     }
  unset($key,$value);  // always tidy up after foreach loops.
```

- [**A better fix can be found exampled here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344741/binding-multiple-values-in-pdo)

Comment: @RickyWijaya I don't know what your comment relates to but see my updated answer for an improved fix.

Comment: i just wana to use one , 1 try function 1 not work then i change to function 2 not work . so maybe if somebody can correct one of them

Comment: same like RamRaider when i do input the categoryName : tech and categorySort : 3 , what get input to server is categoryName : 3 and categorySort : 3

Comment: use PHP error logging to check for processing errors and warnings (more importantly).

Comment: [this](http://imgur.com/vflwRhJ) , [this2](http://imgur.com/xJj80px) here the screenshot , i got no error

Comment: i find it $stmt99->execute($array); that variable array i forget . thanks for the help