# php pdo bind array parameters in bindParam without foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is there a way to bind array params in `bindParam` function of `pdo` without using `foreach` statement? (something like `mysql.connector` in `python`).
the `foreach` version would be like this:

```
$data = array('name'=>'something','job'=>'something else');
foreach($data as $key => $value){
    $stmt->bindParam(':'.$key, $value);
}
```

Comment: You can bind multiple parameters via array in the pdo execute:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344741/binding-multiple-values-in-pdo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many PDO users think they have to use `bindParam()`. You don't.

You can pass an array directly to `execute()` with all your parameter values. It's this easy:

```
$stmt->execute($data);
```

If you used named parameters in your SQL, use a hash array. If you used positional parameters, use a plain array.

For more complete code examples, read them here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: the keys in my $data array does not have a colon(:) at the beginning, so maybe I should use array_map to modify it and then use execute

Comment: @MehrdadEP It's okay if they don't have the colons. It will still work.

Comment: @Don'tPanic ok, thank you.

Comment: Yes, in an old version of PDO the array keys needed to have a colon prefix, but that was a long time ago. There's no reason for that anymore.

Comment: @BillKarwin I guess I got confused with the documentation which specifies them. I didn't know about the implementation till now. thank you